# Tkinter visible area?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to establish whether my tag in a Tkinter widget is visible or not. I know about .yview and .see, however, I do not want to shift (scroll) the screen until the selected text which is tagged is not visible (is off current window borders).

My widget is based on [tkinterhtml](https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml) which is a Python wrapper for [tkhtml](http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/tkhtml.html), it supports basic methods of tkinter Text widget like yview and tag, so any help on how to do this in basic tkinter widgets is appreciated.

Is it possible to establish whether some text is visible or not preferably without messing around with x and y coordinates directly?

I found that .yview() or .yview(node) gives me such coordinates as (0.0, 0.17615077926785067), however, I cannot call .yview without actually shifting the screen. This probably can be done with getting current visible area coordinates with .yview(), then getting current selection coordinates with .yview(node), then setting old coordinates with .yview_moveto, but the screen noticeably flickers during this and I'm not getting appropriate results (maybe owing to some bug in my code).

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

for any given index you can use `.bbox` [If the character is not visible, returns None.](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-methods.html)

```
if text.bbox("end") is None:
    print("not at bottom yet")
else:
    print("at the bottom")
```

and if you need to check for a tag instead you can just use the `.tag_ranges` method to get all the indices for that tag:

```
def is_tag_showing(text_widget, tag):
    return any(text.bbox(idx) is not None for idx in text.tag_ranges(tag))
```

Although it is worth noting that if a tag is only *partially* on the screen this will return True.  To check if all text with the tag is visible you would just switch `any` with `all`.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it seems that bbox in tkhtml never generates None or an empty value. When node is not visible, bbox value is something like (248,1165,523,1182) (man says: The first two integers are the x and y coordinates of the top-left corner of the bounding-box, the later two are the x and y coordinates of the bottom-right corner of the same box. If the node does not generate content, then an empty string is returned.), and I can say that this is not visible because 1182 > 1080 (my screen resolution is 1920x1080). Maybe there is a better way than checking geometry every time?